# With a React Hooks' setter, how can I set data before the component renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I export a JS object called Products to this file, just to replace a real API call initially while I am building/testing. I want to set the function's state to the object, but mapped. I have the component looking like this:

```
function App() {
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);
  const [days, setDays] = useState([]);
  const roomsMapped = products.data.map(room => ({
    id: room.id,
    title: room.title
  }))

  useEffect(() => {
    setRooms(roomsMapped);
  })

  return ( etc )
```

This returns the following error: `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded`.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here, but am pretty new to React and Hooks. How can I set this data before the component renders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare it as initial value of `rooms`

```
 const Component = () =>{
     const [rooms, setRooms] = useState(products.data.map(room => ({
         id: room.id,
         title: room.title
      })))
 }
```

You can also use [lazy initial state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58539813/lazy-initial-state-where-to-use-it/58539958#58539958) to avoid reprocessing the initial value on each render

```
 const Component = () =>{
     const [rooms, setRooms] = useState(() => products.data.map(room => ({
         id: room.id,
         title: room.title
      })))
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `useEffect` to this

```
useEffect(() => {
    setRooms(roomsMapped);
  },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Lazy initialisation` with function as a parameter of `useState`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState(() => {
    // May be a long computation initialization
    const data = products.data || [];
    return data.map(({ id, title }) => ({ id, title }));
  });

  return (
    // JSX stuffs
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use default props for this.set initial value with empty list .

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 'Error: Maximum update depth exceeded', because your useEffect function doesn't have dependency array. Best way to fix this is to pass empty array as the second argument to useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setRooms(roomsMapped);
  },[]) <= pass empty array here
```

this will prevent component to re render, it you want your component to re render on props change you can pass the props in the array like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setRooms(roomsMapped);
  },[props.props1,props.props2])
```

here you can pass as many props as you want...