# Questions about initializing `useState` with `Date.now()`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using an API to retrieve latest posts from Firestore. The API is something is like this

```js
function loadFeedPosts(
  createdAtMax,
  limit
) {
  return db
    .collection("posts")
    .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
    .where("createdAt", "<", createdAtMax)
    .limit(limit)
    .get()
    .then(getDocsFromSnapshot)
}
```

`createdAtMax` is the time we need to specify in order to retrieve the posts.

And I have a `Feed` component. It looks like this.

```js
function Feed() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(Date.now())
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(3)

  useEffect(() => {
    loadFeedPosts(currentTime, limit).then(posts => {
      setPosts(posts)
    })
  }, [currentTime, limit])

  return (
    <div className="Feed">
      <div className="Feed_button_wrapper">
        <button className="Feed_new_posts_button icon_button">
          View 3 New Posts
        </button>
      </div>

      {posts.map(post => (
        <FeedPost post={post} />
      ))}

      <div className="Feed_button_wrapper">
        <button
          className="Feed_new_posts_button icon_button"
          onClick={() => {
            setLimit(limit + 3)
          }}
        >
          View More
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

So when people click on the `View More` button, it will go retrieve 3 more posts.

My question is, since clicking on the `View More` button triggers a re-render, I assume the line `const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(Date.now())` will get run again, does the `Date.now()` which serves as the initial value for `currentTime` get evaluated again for every re-render?

I tested it myself by logging out `currentTime`, and it seemed **not** updating for every render. According to the React doc https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state, I thought only when using Lazy initial state, the `initialState` is only calculated once. But here I am not using Lazy initial state, how come it is not calculated every time the component re-renders?

Although **the intended behavior of the initial state of `currentTime` is exactly stays the same for every re-render**, I am just baffled why it didn't get re-calculated for every re-render since I am not using Lazy initial state

Comment: the argument in `useState()` defines the `initialValue` which gets only set on the first render

Comment: @sebastian-ruehmann then why do we have Lazy initial state? Isn't that redundent?

Comment: *If the initial state is the result of an expensive computation, you may provide a function instead* https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state

Comment: I think you emphasized the wrong thing in the explanation of `React's useState Lazy initial State` Docs. The reason for having the `Lazy initial state` is not that by default the initialValue is recomputed on render. Rather is it made for having an exclusive and only initially called "State set up function" which is memoized until the component unmounts

Comment: @sebastian-ruehmann Hi still trying to understand the difference here. so let's say if we have a simple `useState` hook like this `const [myState, setMyState] = useState(fn())` and a Lazy initial state `const [myState, setMyState] = useState( () => fn() )` . will both `fn()` be run for only the first initial render or the first hook will run `fn()` for every re-render?

Comment: `const [myState, setMyState] = useState(fn())` will disregarded being called on rerender `const [myState, setMyState] = useState( () => fn())` on initial render only. Good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58539958/13745258

Answer (score 2):

Using `useState` you are providing only the initial value, as the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable) about the `useState` hook says:

> What do we pass to useState as an argument? The only argument to the
>   useState() Hook is the initial state.

The reason why we have lazy initialization is because in subsequent renders the `initialValue` will be disregarded, and if it is the result of an expensive computation you may want to avoid to re-execute it.

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState(expensiveComputation());
// expensiveComputation will be executed at each render and the result disregarded

const [value, setValue] = useState(() => expensiveComputation());
// expensiveComputation will be executed only at the first render
```

Comment: Sorry I think there is a misunderstanding. Maybe I didn't express myself clearly. Not updating the current time every time the component re-renders is the intended behavior I wanted. I was just confused with the usage of ` Lazy initial state`. I thought only when using Lazy initial state we get the initialState calculated once, otherwise it is re-calculated every time the component rerenders

Comment: Ah ok, nice to know. I know understand you confusion, I've updated my answer, hope it helps ;)

Comment: Also, if  `currentTime` isn't meant to be used to re-render the component, consider using a mutable variable with `useRef`

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. This is exactly what I thought. So as you said, for `const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(Date.now())`, `Date.now()` will be executed at each render, but it doesn't affect the `value` even thought it is the initial value? That's why after every re-render when we print out `currentTime` we will see the same value?

Comment: Yeah exactly, the state should persist between renders so the Date is computed but the value is ignored

Answer (score 2):

`useState()` initializes the state with mount, it runs just before first render.

From the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) :

> During **the initial render**, the returned state (state) is the same as
>   the value passed as the first argument (initialState).

**Why do we need lazy initial state?**

Lets say we derive our initial state after some high complexity function. Lets try without lazy state approach :

```js
const A = () => {
  const [a, setA] = useState("blabla")
  const processedA = processA(a) // Wait! this will run on every render!, 
  // so i need to find a way to prevent to be processed after first render.

  return ...
}
```

To implement function that only run for once, i should keep track of renders with useRef :

```
const A = () => {
  const [a, setA] = useState("blabla")
  let processedA

  const willMount = useRef(true);
  if (willMount.current) {
    processedA = processA(a)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    willMount.current = false;
  }), []);

 return ...
}
```

What an ugly approach, isnt it?

Another approach can be using useEffect, but this time it will work on second render after mount. So i will have unnecessary first render :

```js
const A = () => {
  const [a, setA] = useState("blabla")

  useEffect(()=>{
    const processedA = processA(a)
    setA(processedA)
  }, [a])

  return ...
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I don't understand, since the initialState is only calculated once during the initial render, then why do we need Lazy initial state?

Comment: @Joji i tried to explain why we need lazy initial state

Comment: Hi @Kerematam :) I've found this blogpost really interesting https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/. It is advised to never lie about the `useEffect` dependencies and to think in "hooks" instead of "lifecycle"

Comment: @DevidFarinelli Thanks for the article! and yeah, i have tendency to code hooks in life cycle perspective:D