# on first render, data shows null on console log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm using useEffect and filling my state on the first render

```
 const [data, setData ] = useState({});
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);


 useEffect(() => {
   fetchData();
 }, [])

 const fetchData = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        await sanityAPI.fetch(
            `url/ToGetData`
          ).then((res) => {
            setData(res)
            setIsLoading(false)
          }).catch((err) => {
              console.log(err)
          });
 }
```

when page is rendered the first time, if I console.log(data,'first time') in useEffect data, it gives me null

but after the first time if I go and just add another string in console.log(data,'second time'), and save it, the data shows, on the console.log.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why are you using both await and then ?

Comment: `data` will be empty object (`{}`) on the initial render, and then eventually updated by the `fetch`. `useEffect` runs *after* a render. This is normal. Is there an issue? React state updates are also asynchronously processed, so if you are trying to log the state right after enqueueing an update it will be the state value from the *current* render cycle.

Comment: useEffect runs *after* the first render. You can pass a callback to `useState` to [lazy load your initial state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58539813/lazy-initial-state-what-is-and-where-to-use-it) if need be, but otherwise just account for initial empty state followed by update after the useEffect runs.

Comment: Is there another workaround, that I can do this, because I need the data that I'm getting, to call other functions that will check for other things.

Comment: Can you update your question to include your actual relevant code?

Comment: Why don't you just use another useEffect call to execute those other functions you are talking about after the data is loaded?

Comment: @DRewReese I need to manipulate the data, validate if a condition renders then display data if that conditions is true. The point is that on the first render isn't filling data in useState.

Comment: @DanZuzevich I don't know, if you can call two times useEffect. Can you explain that to me

Comment: Well, you can't do any of that until you've fetched the data, which as we pointed out, is pretty normal in React, and your code should handle missing/empty data for the initial and first few renders until state is set and ready. You can use as many React hooks as the component needs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is really no way around what you are talking about. You need to wait until your data has been fetched, then you can execute those functions that depend on that data. You can add an additional useEffect to handle what to do after the data has been fetched and set to state.

Personally, sometimes I find it easier to set the data to null initially, rather than an empty object. This makes it easy to check in useEffect, JSX code etc if your data is available. Otherwise you'd have to do something like `Object.keys(data).length > 0` each time to see if you can use your data.

I've also rewrote some of your code, because you probably shouldn't be mixing `await` with `then`.

```
const [data, setData ] = useState(null);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);


 useEffect(() => {
   fetchData();
 }, [])

 useEffect(() => {
   if(data) {
     // do stuff here
   }
   
 }, [data])

 const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true)
      const res = await sanityAPI.fetch(`url/ToGetData`)
      setData(res)
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error) 
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false)
    } 
 }

return (
  <div>
   ...bunch of code

   {
     data && <div>{data.foo}</div>
   }
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Depending on what the object is and what needs to be rendered, `Object.values(state).map(....` sufficiently handles empty initial object state just fine.

Comment: Yup agreed. All depends on how the objects being used in render.